# Can't get any data from sqlite db on Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have a DB helper that does this function:

```
public Cursor getCourseNames() throws SQLException {
    mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    return mDb.query("Course",null, COURSE_ROWID, null, null, null, null, null); 
}
```

The table it is pulling from looks like this:

```
private static final String COURSE_ID = "CourseID";
private static final String COURSE_NAME = "Name";
private static final String COURSE_CODE = "CourseCode";
private static final String COURSE_ROWID = "_id";


private static final String COURSE_CREATE =
    "create table " +
    "Course" + " ( " + 
    COURSE_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
    COURSE_ID + "integer not null," +
    COURSE_NAME + "text not null, " +
    COURSE_CODE + "text not null" + ");";
```

In my main activity I try this and get a null pointer...

```
public void buildCoursetoChapterList(){

    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getCourseNames();
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, null, null);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Anyone have an idea what my problem is?
I put data into the db earlier on:

```
if(dbHelper.checkCourseForData() !=null)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.classlist);
}
else
{
    dbHelper.addFirstClassToDb(course_code, name, course_id);
    Log.d+i("Course added to DB", course_code + " " + name + " " + course_id);
}
```

tried this and still nothing, I want to select all the Name values within Course.
No clue... losing hope.

```
public Cursor checkCourseForData() throws SQLException {
    String[] values = {COURSE_NAME};
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query("Course",values,COURSE_ROWID + "=" + "Name", null, null, null, null, null); 
    if (mCursor != null) { mCursor.moveToFirst(); } 

    return mCursor;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be this

```
public Cursor getCourseNames() throws SQLException {
    String[] values = {COURSE_NAME};
    mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    return mDb.query("Course",values,COURSE_ROWID, null, null, null, null, null); 
}
```

Explanation :

the medthod in the api has been defined as

> public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection,
>   String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)

So you need to pass the strings accordingly.

User my example as a reference it works for me

```
    private String name;
private String Events_Table = "events";
private String[] Columns = {"_id", "Name", "Date", "Time_Slot", "Venue", "Details", "EHName", "EHNumber"} ;
private String WhereClause = Columns[1]+"=?" ;

    Cursor cursor = db.query(Events_Table, Columns, WhereClause, new String[] {name}, null, null, null);
```

Consider Reading this

Parameters

**table**  The table name to compile the query against.

**columns**  A list of which columns to return. Passing null will return all columns, which is discouraged to prevent reading data from storage that isn't going to be used.

**selection**  A filter declaring which rows to return, formatted as an SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself). Passing null will return all rows for the given table.

**selectionArgs**  You may include ?s in selection, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs, in order that they appear in the selection. The values will be bound as Strings.

**groupBy**  A filter declaring how to group rows, formatted as an SQL GROUP BY clause (excluding the GROUP BY itself). Passing null will cause the rows to not be grouped. 
having  A filter declare which row groups to include in the cursor, if row grouping is being used, formatted as an SQL HAVING clause (excluding the HAVING itself). Passing null will cause all row groups to be included, and is required when row grouping is not being used.

**orderBy**  How to order the rows, formatted as an SQL ORDER BY clause (excluding the ORDER BY itself). Passing null will use the default sort order, which may be unordered.

Comment: For anyone wondering since there's 0 explanation given and its hard to notice: He switched the order of the params

Comment: But what about the problem of my declaration
private static final String COURSE_ROWID = "_id";
The parameter is looking or a String[] array and I declared as a normal string? It does nothing still :/

Comment: @Simon I added some explanation, please review. Thanks

Comment: @wilxjcherokee Check my Answer Now and you'll find the solution.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I still get this as an error now
05-17 12:19:44.832: E/AndroidRuntime(17465): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Comment: negative rater care to comment ?

Comment: I upvoted but it doesn't seem to work still. might be something I did